# How can I find to which stack exchange did I post a question?

Tags: support

I posed a question on stack exchange about Bessel functions and radiation from loop antenna. I suppose I asked in physics.stackexchange, but maybe math.stackexchange. Heck, could have been anywhere. I know I asked.

How can i find my posted questions? Thank, T.

Comment: The only question you’ve asked is on physics but it was a long time ago. You can’t find it because it’s been deleted. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/369803/what-is-relationship-between-ac-susceptibility-and-epr-signal

Comment: I have found posts of mine by googling `stackexchange (some key words) aparente001`.

Answer (score 6):

I see that your question is deleted.  Had it not been deleted, you could have found it in this way:

- Go to https://stackexchange.com
- Click on your avatar
- Click on "all actions"
- Click on either "posts," or "all."
- Scroll down until you find your question.

Comment: (Does not show deleted content)